# Apache Spark node asking master for more data?

Tags: apache-spark

I'm trying to benchmark a few approaches to putting an image processing algorithm into apache spark. For one step in this algorithm, a computation on a pixel in the image will depend on an unknown amount of surrounding data, so we can't partition the image with guaranteed sufficient overlap a priori.

One solution to that problem I need to benchmark is for a worker node to ask the master node for more data when it encounters a pixel with insufficient surrounding data. I'm not convinced this is the way to do things, but I need to benchmark it anyway because of reasons.

Unfortunately, after a bunch of googling and reading docs I can't find any way for a `processingFunc` called as part of `sc.parallelize(partitions).map(processingFunc)` to query the master node for more data from a different partition mid-computation.

**Does a way for a worker node to ask the master for more data exist in spark, or will I need to hack something together that kind of goes around spark?**

Answer (score 0):

Master Node in Spark is for allocating the resources to a particular job and once the resources are allocated, the Driver ships the complete code with all its dependencies to the various executors.

The first step in every code is to load the data to the Spark cluster. You can read the data from any underlying data repository like Database, filesystem, webservices etc.

Once data is loaded it is wrapped into an RDD which is partitioned across the nodes in the cluster and further stored in the workers/ Executors Memory. Though you can control the number of partitions by leveraging various RDD API's but you should do it only when you have valid reasons to do so.

Now all operations are performed over RDD's using its various methods/ Operations exposed by RDD API. RDD keep tracks of partitions and partitioned data and depending upon the need or request it automatically query the appropriate partition.

In nutshell, you do not have to worry about the way data is partitioned by RDD or which partition stores which data and how they communicate with each other but if you do care, then you can write your own custom partitioner, instructing Spark of how to partition your data.

Secondly if your data cannot be partitioned then I do not think Spark would be an ideal choice because that will result in processing of everything in 1 single machine which itself is contrary to the idea of distributed computing.

Not sure what is exactly your use case but there are people who have been leveraging Spark for Image processing. see here for the [comments from Databricks](https://forums.databricks.com/questions/612/can-i-process-image-or-video-files-with-spark.html)